# Redirect into two different page after login.jsp according user category

Tags: jsp, redirect, authentication

I have created a `login.jsp` with some login username and password. Users are categorized into A and B. Then I have to redirect each user according to the user category. I also need to retrieve the username in the next page. My form in `login.jsp` page is something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action='<%= response.encodeURL("j_security_check") %>'
```

Do I have to use `javax.servlet.Filter`? what should be added in `web.xml`?

Anyone had an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a if condition in servlet like this

```
// Get the user type
if (userType == Type1){
response.sendRedirect("Page1.jsp");
}else{
response.sendRedirect("Page2.jsp");
}
```